# Flutter not able to run

Tags: flutter, dart-ui

ERROR:D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 96089 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:151)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:138)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:859)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position: null
at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.3.70.java:0)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:75)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:28)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:27)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.b(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:2)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:11)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:136)
... 38 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.f: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 96089 > 65536)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.JT.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:14)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.JT.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:22)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.n30.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:524)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.i30.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:7)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.F2.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:371)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.F2.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:455)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:756)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:1)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.70_49b71801b8b3de79ea68cec3bf950786c8f90f7a560cea4a2d23a82079b17d04:24)
... 41 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
> There was a failure while executing work items
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
> Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
[!] App requires Multidex support
Multidex support is required for your android app to build since the number of methods has exceeded 64k. See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support for more information. You may pass the --no-multidex flag to skip Flutter's multidex support to use a manual solution.

```
Flutter tool can add multidex support. The following file will be added by flutter:

    android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/app/FlutterMultiDexApplication.java
```

cannot prompt without a terminal ui
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I am facing problem while running main.dart.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

1. **Enable multidex.**

Open `[project_folder]/app/build.gradle` and add following lines.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```